# How do make this slider change to a custom slide number?

Tags: javascript

I have this slider, I want to be able to click the slide number instead of "next" and "previous", then it go to that slide, currently there's functions that allow you to change to next/previous (this is not my code):

```
jQuery(".next").click(ms_go_next);
```

and

```
jQuery(".previous").click(function(){
```

I've found a function in the code called "ms_go_slide", I take it this function will take a custom number and change it to that slide:

```
`function ms_go_slide(slide,direction) {

if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

var fs = jQuery('fieldset').filter(':visible');
next_fs = jQuery('fieldset.section'+slide);

ms_set_height(next_fs);

//show the next fieldset

next_fs.css({'left':((direction == 'ltr')? '-100%':'100%'),'top':0});
next_fs.show(); 

//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {

        if (direction == 'ltr') {
            var a = (100 * now).toString() + '%';
            var b = '-'+(100 * (1 - now)).toString() + '%';
            current_fs.css({'left':b});
            next_fs.css({'left':a});
        } else {
            var a = '-'+(100 * now).toString() + '%';
            var b = (100 * (1 - now)).toString() + '%';
            current_fs.css({'left':b});
            next_fs.css({'left':a});
        }
        opacity = 1 - now;

        next_fs.css({'opacity':opacity});

    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){

        current_fs.hide();
        current_fs.attr('style','');
        current_fs = next_fs;
        console.log('setting:214', current_fs);
        current_fs.attr('style','');
        current_fs.show();

        animating = false;
    }
});
```

HTML is here

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <form id="msform" form="" action="https://loancalc.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST"> 
   <!-- progressbar --> 
   <ul id="progressbar"> 
    <li class="active" style="width:33.333333333333%"></li>
    <li style="width:33.333333333333%"></li>
    <li style="width:33.333333333333%"></li>
   </ul> 
   <!-- fieldsets -->
   <div class="fieldsets" style="height: 161px;">
    <fieldset class="section1" style="display: block;">
     <p class="inputfield ">How much money do you need?<br /> <select class="minimal required" name="loanamount" required=""> <option value="Select...">Select...</option> <option value="under $5000">under $5000</option> <option value=" under $10000"> under $10000</option> <option value=" under $20000"> under $20000</option> <option value=" under $50000 "> under $50000 </option> <option value="under $100000">under $100000</option> <option value=" over $100000"> over $100000</option> </select></p> 
     <div class="buttons">
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
     </div>
     <div class="buttons_working"> 
      <p class="working_loading"></p>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="section2">
     <p class="inputfield ">What's your monthly revenue?<br /> <select class="minimal required" name="yourincome" required=""> <option value="Select...">Select...</option> <option value="under $5000">under $5000</option> <option value=" under $10000"> under $10000</option> <option value=" under $20000"> under $20000</option> <option value=" under $50000 "> under $50000 </option> <option value="under $100000">under $100000</option> <option value=" over $100000"> over $100000</option> </select></p> 
     <div class="buttons">
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
     </div>
     <div class="buttons_working"> 
      <p class="working_loading"></p>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="section3">
     <p class="inputfield ">Your name<br /> <input id="yourname" name="yourname" type="text" class="required" value="" /></p> 
     <p class="inputfield ">Email address<br /> <input id="youremail" name="youremail" type="text" class="required" value="" /></p> 
     <p class="inputfield ">Phone number<br /> <input id="yourphone" type="tel" name="yourphone" value="" placeholder="0123-456789" maxlength="11" /><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery("input[name=\"yourphone\"]").mask("0000-000000");});</script></p>
     <p class="inputfield ">Business name<br /> <input id="businessname" name="businessname" type="text" value="" /></p> 
     <div class="buttons">
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="ms_submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
     </div>
     <div class="buttons_working"> 
      <p class="working_loading"></p>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="section_success">
     <h2 class="section_success_title">Success</h2>
     <p class="section_success_blurb">You successfully submitted the form</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="section_failure">
     <h2>Oops</h2>
     <p>The form didn't submit</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="section_loading">
     <p class="loading"></p>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

So I added this bit of code:

```
jQuery('input').click(ms_go_slide(this.slide));
```

It doesn't work though, not being able to do simple things like this makes me want to give up coding, I just think I can't really do it, I would expect it to just click and have the answer, but it doesn't. Need advice.

The slider is [here](https://loancalc.000webhostapp.com/getleads)

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f23yvca8/)

Comment: What does `this.slide` refer to? Where are you getting the number from? Also, you should be using an anonymous function as the callback, i.e. `jQuery('input').click(function)() { ms_go_slide(<slideNumber>); });`

Comment: I added it thinking that it would refer to whatever slide number is clicked, there's numbers on the top that display what the current slide is.

Comment: Please create a [**minimal, concrete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): it's difficult to see what you're trying to do. You're not including the minimal markup and code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any html in this plugin folder, it's all php and js so not sure how you would reproduce it.

I am unsure of what code I could show you, I don't even know what part of it I should include myself.

Comment: You don't need to share PHP: this is purely a client-side issue, so all you need is to create an MCVE using the output HTML from your server. We aren't clairvoyants here so it's not possible that we telepathically figure out what's wrong without the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Terry, how do I do that? Would I use the devtools or would I inspect the page source, the plugin is here (https://loancalc.000webhostapp.com/getleads), is there any easier way of extracting the html?

Comment: Just inspect the page and copy the HTML...?

Comment: Like "copy outerHTML", it doesn't come formatted and indented.

Comment: Then paste it into a prettifier. There’s a lot of that online. Just google search it.

Comment: @Terry i've added the html